# Importing project from eclipse to intellij : error with JDBC mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, intellij-idea

I imported my project from Eclipse to Intellij et when I run it, I get an error when loading JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' : "org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'"

The build works perfectly on eclipse and my library dependency is correctly set..

Any ideas? Is it because I am using Intellij Community Edition?

EDIT : I found the solution, i needed to set to scope of this library to runtime instead of provided : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCC2p.jpg

Comment: have you added the drivers jar to your project?

Comment: I have added the jar as a library like this : http://imgur.com/eAOdxSK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, i needed to set to scope of mysql-connector-java to runtime instead of provided : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCC2p.jpg.

But, it's still strange that in eclipse, it is working with a provided scope.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Libraries --> Add (the green + button) and add the mysql connector.jar
Probabily you are missing the library

Comment: I just checked again and it seems i added it correctly (see the link ) but maybe I'm doing it wrong?
http://imgur.com/eAOdxSK

Comment: have you solved it yet?  If no than check Your line of code of ClassForName.. it should look like this :

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`  
@Lap1n